# Determine the number of instances of an object in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

How can I determine the number of instances of a specific object in memory in C#?

Actually I want to call the garbage collector when the unreferenced instances of an object increases beyond a certain limit.

Comment: Is the object under your control? Can you modify its source code?

Comment: Any particular reason you would like to do manual memory management instead of leaving this task to the CLR which undoubtedly would do it better?

Comment: what is the reason you like to change the memory contents?

Comment: No, you don't want to. By trying to manually control the garbage collector, you'll just ruin the performance while making the program harder to maintain too. (Note, that handling objects with destructors requires a *lot* of extra work from the runtime, too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do that you can use static field for the class( [Infos](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/04/c-static-members/) )

And then in constructor you increase the static field..
It is just an idea..